# Why does Android's android.graphics.Color have a public constructor?

Tags: android, graphics, awt

For my first ever StackOverflow question...

android.graphics.Color only contains static utility methods, it isn't a "real" Object like java.awt.Color.  Why does it have a public constructor?  Frankly, it's just confusing, I saw that and thought it was a real object for a couple of minutes.

Comment: I looked at the source, and couldn't actually see the constructor in the source. http://androidadb.com/source/pdn-slatedroid-read-only/eclair/frameworks/base/graphics/java/android/graphics/Color.java.html

Comment: I see it in the JavaDocs.  [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#Color()] (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#Color())

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that. I'm thinking it is an oversight in the javadocs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We just forgot to specify a private constructor. Java classes automatically inherit from the default public constructor if you don't specify any. It's just an oversight. Sorry :)

Comment: If I can get Romain Guy to answer all my Android questions I'll certainly ask more.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like there's an explicit one, but Google just left the default one in for some reason. I don't particularly see a reason for it either. Could've just been something they missed.